# Why and how did "Shinto shrine" largely replace "Shinto temple"?

Tags: collocation, religion, architecture

According to [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shinto%20shrine%2Cbuddhist%20temple%2Cshinto%20temple%2C%20buddhist%20shrine&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cshinto%20shrine%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BShinto%20shrine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BShinto%20Shrine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSHINTO%20SHRINE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbuddhist%20temple%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BBuddhist%20temple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBuddhist%20Temple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBUDDHIST%20TEMPLE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cshinto%20temple%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BShinto%20temple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BShinto%20Temple%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSHINTO%20TEMPLE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbuddhist%20shrine%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BBuddhist%20shrine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBuddhist%20Shrine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBUDDHIST%20SHRINE%3B%2Cc0), "Shinto shrine" and "Shinto temple" were roughly equal in popularity until the 1930s, but nowadays, "Shinto shrine" is roughly 9 or 10 times more common than "Shinto temple", while by means of comparison, "Buddhist temple" is still much more common than "Buddhist shrine", so it isn't that the word "shrine" became wildly more popular.

Wiktionary describes a shrine (in this context) as "A holy or sacred place dedicated to a specific deity, ancestor, hero, martyr, saint, or similar figure of awe and respect, at which said figure is venerated or worshipped.", and a temple as "A house of worship". The two terms "temple" and "shrine" have been [around for centuries](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shrine%2Ctemple&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshrine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctemple%3B%2Cc0), though the terms "Buddhism" and "Shinto" [are comparatively recent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=buddhism%2Cshinto&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cbuddhism%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BBuddhism%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBUDDHISM%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cshinto%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BShinto%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSHINTO%3B%2Cc0).

Looking through the Wikipedia article on [Shinto shrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinto_shrine), I didn't notice any changes in architecture around that time that "Shinto temple" fell out of favour, suggesting that it wasn't the structure of Shinto shrines had changed from something resembling a "temple" to that resembling a "shrine".

However, the Wikipedia article did give an explanation, although without any citations:

> Today, the term "Shinto shrine" in English is used in opposition to
>   "Buddhist temple" to mirror in English the distinction made in
>   Japanese between Shinto and Buddhist religious structures.

Did English-speakers decide to use different words for different religions, and allocate "temple" for Buddhism, and "shrine" for Shinto? Was a memo passed around to that effect, telling people to stop using "Shinto temple"?

Comment: It seems the presence of Kami in the Shinto shrines is a viable distinction. The shrine is viewed as a container for something quite particular. I also ran across the 'explanation' that a shrine is a place to pray, a temple is a place of worship. Although I don't seem to know enough about religions for that to be of much use.

Answer (score 1):

A shrine is a memorial to the dead, a temple is a place or worship. After the 1930s and WW2 the Japanese had a lot more dead to memorialize, hence a lot more temples were converted into shrines. Also, a lot of western attention has been on shrines that memorialize war criminals, which would explain the increased frequency of the term in use in English text.